# spring to replace placeholders in log4j

Tags: spring, logging, log4j

I would like to make my log4j.xml file configurable in different environment.
I would like to define the log level like this:

```
<logger name="com.mycompany">
    <level value="${log.level}" />
</logger>
```

where log.level is defined in a property file

mypropertyfile.properties
log.level=DEBUG

is it possible using spring?

Comment: Did you have read about PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer?

Comment: I believe that the log4j.xml file is outside the realm of spring.  If you instead write a log4j configurator class you can configure the log4j properties using spring injection.

Answer (score 0):

You can put properties file location into your customized context loader listener, which extends from ContextLoaderListener